# How do I fix my django admin page not loading css although having correct configuration?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I am aware this question has been asked a thousand times, but none of the solutions have worked for me... I was working on the Django tutorial, but when I created the superuser, and entered the admin page, the css was missing.

Buy when I check the page source from chrome, and click one of the css references in the html, my computer manages to download the stylesheet.
It only had a relative path, and when using chrome's debugger, I can see the page taking some time to download the css.
So I guess the *static paths are configured correctly*, the page actually loads the css, but somehow it is not reflected in the rendered page.

**settings.py**

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    (other patterns)
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

What I have tried besides editing settings:

- Deleting static files and running `manage.py collectstatic` every time i modified any files
- Adding base dir + "templates" to TEMPLATES
- changing DEBUG from False to True again

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**
Hello, and thanks for the suggestions.
Since I was only at the beginning of the project, I decided to just delete the project altogether, and try again from the tutorial step by step.
It started working in Google Chrome, but not in other browsers.
In Microsoft Edge, and Opera, the CSS is still not working.
I don't know if this can be fixed by changing something in Django or if it is just a problem with the browsers.
Below is the new static settings in settings.py after retrying the setup.

**Settings.py**

```
import os
import mimetypes
mimetypes.add_type("text/css", ".css", True)

#Omitted because no changes#

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__),'..','..','/static')
```

**File structure**

```
GBB - GBBDjango - GBBDjango   - settings.py
    |           | - manage.py | - (and other files)
    | - GBBVenv(Files for venv)
    | -  static
```

So I believe STATIC_ROOT is set correctly because it goes back 2 files then searches for 'static'.

Maybe it would be appropriate to change the title since this may not be a Django problem anymore, but I don't know what else should be done.

Comment: Can you access the css urls from the browser? *Instead of just guessing*. Also, please do not host staticfiles with django `serve()` or `static()`. Check out whitenoise or something.

Comment: Yes I can. Typing in the css url resulted in my browser downloading the css. And I was just doing the basic tutorial do I really need whitenoise to do this? I thought it would be needed when I actually deployed it in a server.

Comment: Then the css is available. Just to be sure; you do not see a 404 page when you go to a css file directly?

Comment: I don't know if I understood your question right, but I do not see a 404 when typing in the url, neither when clicking the path inside the page source.

Comment: Does the browser actually download it as an attachment? Do you see any error messages in the browser console?

Comment: No errors in console, and the browser downloads the actual file.

Comment: Ahh there is the issue. The browser should not download it as an attachment. (If I'm understanding it right, navigating to the page will download the file directly to your PC, and it is then located in a downloads folder or whatever?) Try adding `rel="stylesheet" ` to your css links. In `DEBUG` mode, django should auto-host your staticfiles for you anyways, so the `static` func isn't  needed.

Comment: Please show your template code.